How to create a passport stamps for passport ID using Flutter
I am just wondering if it is possible to generate a realistic-looking passport stamp image.
Naturally, passport stamps are usually made by a human dipping a stamp in some ink and then stamping the passport. The result is a little blurred, smudged, or whatever but is uneven.
If you have some code to generate such a stamp (shape is not important) it would be great if you could share it.  It's more the concept.
Thanks in advance.
